# How to copy a text file, and print out the original and copied file in Java

Tags: java

I'm doing a program that needs to take a text file (test.txt) and make a copy of it and print it out.  So far I am only able to print out the original file.  I have searched for a way of doing this but there doesn't seem to be any help that I can understand, I am very new to java.  I am at least looking for guidance, not just the full answer.

my code so far...

```
import java.io.*;

public class Copy{
    public static void main(String [] args){
        try{
            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("test.txt");

            InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(fis);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
            File a = new File("test.txt");
            FileReader fr = new FileReader(a);

            File b = new File("Copied.txt");
            FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(b);

            while(true){
                String line = br.readLine();
                if(line != null){
                    System.out.println(line);

                } else{

                    br.close();
                    break;
                } 
            }
        } catch(FileNotFoundException e){
            System.out.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
        } catch(IOException e){
            System.out.println("Error: " + e.getMessage()); 
        }
    }
}
```

Again any bit of help will be greatly appreciated since I am trying to learn this.  Thank you

Comment: Create a Printwriter[https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html] that prints to a file and `println` into that.

Answer (score 1):

Normally, I'd recommend using `Files.copy` just for it's simplicty, but since you need to "print" the content at the same time, we can make use of your code.

First, however, as a general rule of thumb, if you open it, you should close it.  This makes sure that you're not leaving resources open which might affect other parts of your code.

See [The try-with-resources Statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) for more details.

Next, once you've read a line of text from the source file, you actually need to write it to the destination file, for example...

```
try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("test.txt"))) {
    try (BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("Copied.txt"))) {
        String text = null;
        while ((text = br.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(text);
            bw.write(text);
            bw.newLine();
        }
    }
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    System.out.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
} catch (IOException e) {
    System.out.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Files.copy() if you are using Java 1.7 or higher

`File src = "your File";
 File dest = "your copy target"
 Files.copy(src.toPath(),dest.toPath());`

[Link to Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html)

Answer (score 0):

Change your FileWriter into a PrintStream:

```
PrintStream fw = new PrintStream(b);
```

Then you should be able to write to that file using:

```
fw.println(line);
```